# PHP array of array with string as index

Tags: php, arrays, key

I am not an expert in PHP/MySql so my first idea about how to handle a website with multiple languages and making the PHP code readable was the following:

1) Creating a table with "word, en, it, de, fr" fields, one for each string I want to be translated. For example:

```
 WORD        EN        IT        DE        FR
 title       HomePage  Pagina              No Idea
 thanks      Thank You Grazie    Danke     Merci
```

2) Storing the table in an array of array of strings, so that I could access it in this way:

```
 print $word["thanks"]["it"];
```

which IMHO would make the PHP code very readable (performance is NOT IMPORTANT).

So, I wrote this code to read the data from the DB, and if the translation is empty, I fill the array with "the word in XX is missing" (to avoid pasting all the identical code, I am only showing you one case):

```
 $s = "SELECT word, it, en, de, fr FROM languages";
 $result = $conn->query($s);
 while ($r = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   $word = $r["word"];
   $it = $r["it"];
   // and DE and EN and FR...
   if ($it != "")
     $w["$word"]["$it"] = $it;
   else
     $w["$word"]["$it"] = $word." IT missing";
   // and DE and EN and FR...
 }
```

I tried putting the double quotes, I tried removing them... But every time I print the $w variable, is ALWAYS empty. The intermediate variables read from the DB look ok.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: So when you print it? Right after `while` loop?

Comment: Yes. And even printing directly a single element (like in the example provided) does not do anything :(

Comment: you definitely don't need quotes around `"$word"` and `"$it"`.

Comment: And if `var_dump($r)` -what it shows?

Comment: add `var_dump($r)` after `while ($r = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {` - what do you see?

Comment: Unless you are talking about a really small project, i dont recommend you do the translation using values stored in the database. All frameworks that i know of, have a folder just for this purpose. And each file have not just the word, but the whole sentence translated (since translating each word will probably result in a bad translation)

Comment: $r is fine. It contains all the right values. Ok, I removed the quotes (it was my first "version") but still does not work. Regarding the small/big project, yes it's fairly small, basically for my own usage, and I am sorry I didn't make myself clear :) I will translate WHOLE sentences too, with names like "about_us" that will contain the whole text. And it is not really a translation, I mean to handle a multiple-language website.

Comment: could you change `if($it != '')` to `if($it != NULL && strlen($it) > 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test this.

```
<?php
$s = "SELECT word, it, en, de, fr FROM languages";
$result = $conn->query($s);
$languages = array('it', 'en', 'de', 'fr');
while ($r = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    foreach ($languages as $lang) {
        $word = strval(trim($r["word"]));
        $translated_word = strval(trim($r[$lang]));
        (strlen($translated_word) > 0) ? $w[$word][$lang] = $translated_word : 
                $w[$word][$lang] = $word . " " . strtoupper($lang) . " missing";
    }
}
```

ZioBit edit: Dummy text because SO does not let me modify a single character ;)

Comment: Thank you :) I just removed an extra ";" (after the assign on the first case of the "?") and it works... But still I do not know what was wrong with my code :)

Comment: $w[$word]["it"] = $it;

Comment: Ahahah :) I should stop coding after midnight. I should stop coding after midnight. I should stop coding after midnight. Nobody else noticed it :) Thanks again.